# Virt-manager gives out only one ip for guests. Steals the IP from previous guest

Tags: virtualization, kvm, virsh, virtual-network

I'm completely new to KVM and virt-manager.

I tried to have multiple Ubuntu 18.04.3 VM's. 
In the end they should be accessed from the hosts network. If I'm right I need a routed network setup to achieve this. But I have a different problem before that. 
I installed the first VM with the virt-manager GUI and then cloned every other VM with

```
virt-clone --original ubuntu18.04 --name clu0 --auto-clone
```

If I now start e.g. clu0 it will get assigned an IP.
But if I start clu1, clu1 will get an own IP and clu0 will lose it's IP.
I even tried to give out static IP's in the network config

```
virsh net-edit default
```

Where default is the network in question. 
The VM's even get asigned there defined IP's but still only one VM has it at any given time. 
I'm a bit overwhelmed by the options. I tried to change the network to a routed network but that didn't helped or I did it wrong.

How do I assign every VM it's IP?

Vg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it by help of a colleague.
All clones had the same machine-id. 
I just cleared the file

```
/etc/machine-id
```

That's it.

Vg

Comment: On the physical computer?

Comment: No, on the VM's.
It's quite some time, but if I remember right I just cloned the VM's. So they all hat the same machine id which confused libvirt.

Comment: I checked and my problem was different because my VMs had different IDs from the beginning. My problem was related to the virtual gateway (its DHCP) somehow. I had to reset it.